# Packaging a dotnet core console application with embedded files (.exe or .msi)

Tags: c#, .net-core, package

I know this is a very noob question to ask right now. I'm also new to C# development so please bear with me

Can you guys suggest some packager for dotnet core app that can also package the embedded files included in the development directory?

I've created my project through dotnet cli and I'm using vscode for development. When the develop app is executed, it will run an embedded file inside "file" folder (Don't worry, it works fine. I just need to know a packager to package the app as one executable file. Package it either to .exe or to .msi file).

This is the directory tree of the whole app.

```
- bin
- file
 # The files are stored in here 
   - app1.exe
   - app2.exe
- obj
- Program.cs
- myApp.csproj
```

Suggestions will be very much help. Thanks.

Comment: You could mark the files as embedded resources and then extract them at runtime. It sounds like you might be looking for an installer though, in which case you can create an msi with the WiX toolset.

Comment: Yes, your right. Installer is what I need. Thanks, I'll check the WIX toolset that you suggest and I'll get back if it's the one I need.